# Phoenix unable to generate html template with error "invalid module name"

Tags: html, generator, phoenix-framework

Having trouble running the phx.gen.html templates. This is the command I’m trying

```
mix phx.gen.html Shipments shipmentroutes shipmentroute address:string date:string groups_involved:string
```

with an error message of this

```
mix phx.gen.html, phx.gen.json and phx.gen.context expect a
context module name, followed by singular and plural names of
the generated resource, ending with any number of attributes.
For example:

    mix phx.gen.html Accounts User users name:string
    mix phx.gen.json Accounts User users name:string
    mix phx.gen.context Accounts User users name:string

The context serves as the API boundary for the given resource.
Multiple resources may belong to a context and a resource may be
split over distinct contexts (such as Accounts.User and Payments.User).
```

It doesn’t give any reasoning for why it isn’t a valid module name, so I have no idea how to fix this. I haven't seen anything similar online. Any ideas why phoenix sees this as a bad module name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this, phoenix allows anything that starts with a capital letter for the schema, so it should look like this

```
mix phx.gen.html Shipments Shipmentroutes shipmentroute address:string date:string groups_involved:string
```